# Group Theory - Prove that power set expression is a subset of another

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been asked to prove that: $P(A\setminus B)\subseteq P(A)\setminus P(B) \cup \{\emptyset\}$.

By the laws of group subtraction, I've concluded that:

$\alpha =P(A\setminus B) = P(A \cap B^c) $

$\beta = P(A)\setminus P(B) \cup \{\emptyset\} = P(A)\cap P(B)^c \cup \{\emptyset \}$

But I'm not sure where to go on from here.

It can be said that both sets have a member in the form of the empty set.
But how can I prove that each member of set $\alpha$ is also a member in $\beta$?

Comment: Is neither linear algebra nor group theory nor algebra precalculus.

Comment: Tags have been changed accordingly. Muscle memory from my linear algebra course.

Comment: Right, muscle memory from Linear Algebra causes you to put "Group Theory" in the title.

Comment: Kenny, I just started this course last week. Up until now I was working purely on linear algebra on this site. I meant no harm with my tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X\in\mathcal P(A\setminus B)$, and if $X\ne\emptyset$, then $X\subset A$; therefore, $X\in\mathcal P(A)$. But $X$ contains no element of $B$; in particular, and since $X\ne\emptyset$, $X\notin\mathcal P(B)$. So, $X\in\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B)$.

Comment: Is there an explanation needed for why $X \subset A$? It seems like it can be equal to set $A$, from the definition of the power set and if $A\cap B = \emptyset$

Comment: Yes, $X$ can be equal to $A$. And $C\subset D$ simply means that $C$ is a subset of $D$. In particular, $C$ can be $D$.